# Hibernate and summing values

Tags: sql, hibernate

We have a database that tracks clicks,  so roughly we have a value column and a date column (the date includes mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss).  How can I use hibernate to give me all the values for 1 certain date and add them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate has aggregate functions, like `sum`... refer to this: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-aggregation